# ASP.NET exception error mentions old version of MySQL.Data that is not used in app

Tags: asp.net, mysql

This exception is not showing when debugging locally and shows up only when i browse to the remote url address of the server..

I have FTP'd the MVC 3 app to my remote server and a check of the Bin folder there shows that I have all three MySQL reference assemblies.  All are version `6.4.4.0`.

In my web.config file all of the version numbers relating to those are set to version `6.4.4.0`.

Why am I getting this error message about version `6.3.6.0`, and how can this be solved?

> Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.3.6.0,culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The located  assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.3.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: Can you manually confirm that the web.config file on your server is actually the updated one that refers to `6.4.4.0` ? I know it sounds silly but I'd like to out-rule permissions settings silently failing the file when you tried to upload it (this has happened to me a few times).

Comment: It is.. This was a entire fresh upload of the site... The was no pre-existing files at all on the site..

Comment: After closer examination... There is nowhere in the web.config that it mentions any mysql version numbers at all..

Comment: Also is this a normal looking connection string for a model entity? connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.school.csdl|res://*/Models.school.ssdl|res://*/Models.school.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx;User Id=abcde;password=xxxxxxxxxxxx;Persist Security Info=True;database=xxxxxxxxxxx&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>

Comment: Can you post the section in your web.config that registers the `6.4.4.0` DLLs ... or anything else relevant?

Comment: I can not find anywhere in it where the 6.4.4.0 dlls are registered.

Comment: And what happens then if you stick it in there? (I'm assuming MrMindors post didn't solve the problem?) `<assemblies>       
      <add assembly="MySql.Data, Version=6.4.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
    </assemblies>`

Comment: I am waiting on the ftp to finish cleaning off all the files from the previous publish... I have addeded the assembly reference and changed the copy local to true on the mysql references... So Once it finishes clearing everything off I will try a fresh publish with the new build..

Comment: Ok still getting the same error... This is the current web.config assembly references

Comment: <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />

Comment: <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <add assembly="MySql.Data, Version=6.4.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
      </assemblies>

Comment: Ok so I am still getting the same exception... Just out of curiosity I uploaded the 6.3.6 connectors over the 6.4.4 connectors then it started saying the same exact message but that it was missing the 6.4.4 connectors..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I was worried that I somewhere along the way bits of 6.3.6.0 where left on my system from when I had it installed.. After days of trying to figure this one out I actually have come up with the fix for this issue... I just simply needed to overwrite the version information using assembly binding in the web.config. Once I did that it loads from the remote server error free... Here is what I added to my web.config:

```
    <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.3.6.0" newVersion="6.4.4.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of things to check with this, but the most common one I've run accross was resolved by making sure the assembly is referenced correctly in the Visual Studio project and that the information is correct in the web.config.

In Visual Studio, check the properties on the references for the assemblies

- verify the the version listed.
- check if Specific Version is true/false.
- check if Copy Local is true.
- If the version is wrong, you may have to remove and re-add the reference.

I would guess the exception was not thrown on your local machine because the older version of the assemblies are available on your machine.

The reason your local information is showing in the exception is unrelated to the assembly reference issue. Your local system is where the assembly was built, and so that information is built in for debugging purposes. (If this exception was thrown while you were debugging, VS would bring you to that line of that file.)

Comment: When I first started coding this application i was using the 6.3.6 connector set.... I removed the references and installed the newer 6.4.4.0 connector set a few days back... Is it possible that somewhere there is something still pointing to the 6.3.6 versions?

Comment: Do you have more than one project in the solution? If so you need to check each one for the references. Do you have any pre or post build events that copy files? Are you building clean? (just delete your output directory) Are you using any other libraries that may have been built expecting the 3.6.3 version?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please explain where I put the "Copy local = true"  I do not see it as being part of any property window.  I did find "Always Copy" for the resources.  also where does this go in the web.config

```
<dependentAssembly> 
<assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" /> 
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.3.6.0" newVersion="6.4.4.0" /> 
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Dont worry about the copy local part... Just copy all 3 of the mysql.dll files to your bin directory. and the <dependentAssembly> goes towards the bottom of the web.config in the <runtime> area.. Deploy the files list in this tut also [link](http://www.tigraine.at/2011/01/18/required-files-to-bin-deploy-mvc3/)

Comment: yea I did all that so reposted the question with all my info.  I put the dependent stuff at the top in a runtime area.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the package manager console and then used this to fix this problem:

```
PM> Install-Package MySQL.Data.Entities
```